# Passing a variable to hyperlink text?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

Hope the question is not phrased badly

Is it possible to pass a variable to for example

having an:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '"> $link </a>';
```

so that the hyperlink is the same as the printed out version always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you only need to concatenate it again. Try:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . $link . '</a>';
```